# I want to update the user image, if it's been changed on Facebook / Twitter in my Rails app

Tags: facebook, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using omniauth for user to signin using his Facebook and Twitter account. Everything is working fine till here, getting whatever I need and saving in my db. Now what I want is to update update user info for example: image (more specific) or name or any other thing, how should I do that, so that it's updated information appears in my app as well.

I am posting my user model code where I'm saving the user

```rb
 def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    if user
      return user
    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_user
        return registered_user
      else
        user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,provider:auth.provider,uid:auth.uid,email:auth.info.email,password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],image:auth.info.image)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your code like this:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth)
  user = User.where("(uid = ? AND provider = 'facebook') OR lower(email) = ?", auth.uid, auth.info.email).first || User.new

  #Here you simply update the attributes you want
  user.name = auth.extra.raw_info.name
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0..20]
  user.image = auth.info.image

  user.save
  user
end
```

I highly recommend you include a `oauth_token` and `oauth_expires_at` fields for further extension and usage of the Facebook Graph.

Hope this helps!